# Comments not displaying in Django application

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, comments

I have a simple Django application which I would appreciate a fresh pair of eyes to help me fix this problem.

I have been trying to add the comments functionality from the [djangogirls](https://github.com/DjangoGirls/tutorial-extensions/blob/master/homework_create_more_models/README.md) tutorial to my app called 'timeline'.

So far I have added a comment model to my models.py:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey('timeline.Photo', related_name='comments')
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.text

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

which already contains a photo model:

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    image = ProcessedImageField(upload_to=upload_location, 
        null=True, 
        blank=False,
        processors=[Transpose(), ResizeToFit(1000, 1000, False)],
        #processors=[Transpose(), ResizeToFit(width=960)],
        format='JPEG',
        options={'quality': 50},
        width_field="width_field",
        height_field="height_field")
    height_field = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    width_field = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    description = models.TextField()
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("timeline:detail", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-timestamp", "-updated"]
```

I am struggling to make the comments appear within my html but so far i have followed the instructions and used:

```
{% for comment in post.comments.all %}
    <div class="comment">
    <div class="date">{{ comment.created_date }}</div>
    <strong>{{ comment.author }}</strong>
    <p>{{ comment.text|linebreaks }}</p>
    </div>
{% empty %}
    <p>No comments here yet :(</p>
{% endfor %}
```

view:

```
def photo_detail(request, slug=None):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/accounts/login")

    instance = get_object_or_404(Photo, slug=slug)

    share_string = quote_plus(instance.description)
    context = {
        "title": instance.title,
        "instance": instance,
        "share_string": share_string,
    }

    return render(request, "photo_detail.html", context)
```

I have added the comment model to my admin and I am able to add comments ok but they are simply not displaying and it is driving me nuts. I am sure a fresh pair of eyes will spot this easily. Using Django 1.9 and if any more code required let me know!

code on [Github](https://github.com/davidmcg1985/photozero)

Any help is much appreciated folks! Cheers.

Comment: Show the rest of your template. Do you have a variable called `post`? (might it be called `photo` instead?)

Comment: do you get the `No comments here yet` message displayed? it would help if we could see the view code as well (the view that's rendering that template)

Comment: Show your view that uses that template.  You need to pass comments to the template.  It doesn't look like you are doing that

Comment: I have added the view and also link to code on Github. Thanks!

Comment: @Anentropic yes I get the `No comments here yet` displaying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing any object called `post` into the template for rendering.

You need to change either the context passed from the view:

```
context = {
    "title": instance.title,
    "photo": instance,
    "share_string": share_string,
}
```

Or change the code in the template:

```
{% for comment in instance.comments.all %}
```

(one or the other, not both)

I would suggest to change the context in the view to use the more meaningful name `photo`.